# Softcode Jquery Ajax Data Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Javascript and Jquery and I'm trying to make a function for a flexible api call. What I'm wondering is: is there a way to soft code ajax Data keys?

For example:

```
var call = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {Param: paramValue},
    success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction
  });
```

where `Param` is not an actual parameter in the api call like `url/api?Param=paramvalue`, rather a variable I had defined earlier like `Param = userInput()`. So that if the user enters `'metrics'` , I will call `url/api?metrics`.

If not, is there another way of doing this that I should be made aware of?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use this way to define the data object :

```
var param = "metrics";
var data = {};
data[param] = "";
var call = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction
});
```